# Multiple form with same attribute

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

i was trying to implement a comment system. where everybody can reply of every comment. The system here is when  someone click on a comment a form will be visible and he can reply. So if there is 4 comments so 4 reply box will come. i wanted to store those reply through ajax. But the problem is i can't specify which form is actually submitting and so page got refresh as i specify the form with class. i tried to submit the above form which will be visible under every comment if a user click on the reply button:

```
 <form class="replyComment">
      <textarea name="comment" class="ru_input" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->id}}" name="comment_id">
      <div class="bt_area">
         <button class="floatRight btn btn-primary">Reply
         </button>
      </div>
   </form>
```

And i was trying to submit through following ajax.

```
$( ".replyComment").submit(function( event ) {      
 event.preventDefault();      
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{url("/postReply")}}',
                async: false,
                data: 
                {
                  product_id : {!! json_encode($product->id)!!},
                  comment : event.currentTarget[0].value,
                  comment_id : event.currentTarget[1].value
                },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                  console.log(data)

                },
                error:function(data)
                {

                }

            });
});
```

Comment: Use classes rather then IDs

Comment: Funny, I'm currently working on the same feature, also in laravel

Comment: I tried with class as well. But it again got page refresh .

Comment: What is the parent element of the form?

Comment: use IDs for Form like <form class="replyComment_{{$row->id}}">, keep similar ID for Reply Button, remove submit event of Form, add click event on Reply Button, then by mapping $row->id of Form and Button you will get which Form is submitted

Comment: If you remove the AJAX part, does it prevent refreshing?

Comment: HTML part is coming from ajax. After commented i show the response to the page where reply button is also available. Means only ajax response form got refresh while submitting not the initial form which is there on page.

Comment: Try changing `<button class="floatRight btn btn-primary">Reply
         </button>` to `<input type='button' class="floatRight btn btn-primary" value='Reply'>`

Comment: I tried with that .. but this time form not submitting

Comment: It might be submitting by ajax check console

Answer (score 1):

I changed form ID and added IDs and classes to the inputs and buttons. Passed the ID of the row as data to the click event of submit button. Used the ID of row that is passed as data to get values of the inputs.

```
    <form id="replyComment-{{$row->id}}">
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment-{{$row->id}}" class="ru_input" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" id="comment-id-{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->id}}" name="comment_id">
      <div class="bt_area">
         <button data-id="{{$row->id}}" class="floatRight btn btn-primary comment-button">Reply
         </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And rewrote script:

```
   $( ".comment-button").click(function( event ) {
        var form_id = $(this).data('id');
        event.preventDefault();      
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{url("/postReply")}}',
                async: false,
                data: 
                {
                    product_id : {!! json_encode($product->id)!!},
                    comment : $('#comment-'+form_id).val(),
                    comment_id : $('#comment-id-'+form_id).val()
                },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    console.log(data)

                },
                error:function(data)
                {

                }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to differentiate forms by using an id attributes

```
        <form class="replyComment" id="1">
            <textarea name="comment" class="ru_input" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->id}}" name="comment_id">
            <div class="bt_area">
                <button class="floatRight btn btn-primary">Reply
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form class="replyComment" id="2">
                <textarea name="comment" class="ru_input" placeholder="Write your reply"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->id}}" name="comment_id">
                <div class="bt_area">
                    <button class="floatRight btn btn-primary">Reply
                    </button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

And use '#' insted of '.' while calling like this

```
$( "#1").submit(function( event ) {      
 event.preventDefault();      
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{url("/postReply")}}',
                async: false,
                data: 
                {
                  product_id : {!! json_encode($product->id)!!},
                  comment : event.currentTarget[0].value,
                  comment_id : event.currentTarget[1].value
                },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                  console.log(data)

                },
                error:function(data)
                {

                }

            });
});


$( "#2").submit(function( event ) {      
 event.preventDefault();      
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{url("/postReply")}}',
                async: false,
                data: 
                {
                  product_id : {!! json_encode($product->id)!!},
                  comment : event.currentTarget[0].value,
                  comment_id : event.currentTarget[1].value
                },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                  console.log(data)

                },
                error:function(data)
                {

                }

            });
});
```